# Django: How to follow ManyToMany('self') backwards

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many

> ```
> class c(models.Model):
>     f = models.ManyToManyField(
>         'self', 
>         blank=True, 
>         null=True, 
>         related_name='child_set'
>     )
> ```

I can do :

```
 c.objects.get(pk="1").f
```

But how do I get by '_set'?

```
 c.objects.get(pk="1").child_set
```

doesn't work

i need this:

```
{name:A,parent:[]}
{name:B,parent:[A]}
{name:C,parent:[A,B]}

C.parent.all() == [A,B]
A.parent_set.all() == [B,C]
```

Comment: `instance.f` is already a set - why do you need `instance.child_set`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `ManyToManyField`s that reference `self`, a reverse relationship is not created. This is because it has no use - it would contain all relations that refer to itself - which is what the forward relation does.

You'll find regardless of what you say the `related_name` should be it will be set to `%(field)s_rel_+` (the trailing `+` prevents the relation being created).

So the answer is there is no `child_set` because you can just use `f`.

Comment: Oh, I should mention you can inspect the related name with (for this purpose, not for production) using `c._meta.get_field_by_name('f')[0].related_query_name()`

Comment: Thanks for your attention :) I want to build a tree structure , 
Each node should register the path from the root to their  postion 
(for paths whit length more than one , need M2M) 

I want to reach all of the parents (path) of the specific node by **c.child_set**
 and by **c.f** , reach all of the connected children to specific parent

Comment: By this definition neither is the "parent" or the "child" - they are more like "siblings". This kind of many-to-many structure is more like a web than a tree. For a tree structure, each node can only have one parent, so you would capture that using a `ForeignKey` relationship.

Comment: thnx :) in Django i must use FKey but in **SQLAlchemy** , it is simple : [link](http://www.preetk.com/node/sqlalchemy-part-1-declarative-self-referential-m2m-relationships/)

Comment: This is only half the answer, the many2many relationship symmetry can be disabled. Which will bring back the reverse relationship. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Django's ManyToManyField is symmetrical by default. That means that the through model will be created both ways. If you are pointing to self this means there is no reverse relationship, since the main one includes both.

This behavior can be changed by disabling the symmetry. There is a keyword argument to do that call `symmetrical`. In your example:

```
class c(models.Model):
f = models.ManyToManyField(
    'self', 
    blank=True, 
    null=True, 
    related_name='child_set',
    symmetrical=False
)
```

Answer (score 0):

A good solution for this is to break the C model into two models and create a OneToOneField to the other. This way, the structure becomes a tree rather than a web. The code below illustrates my point:

```
class Boo(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Coo(models.Model):
    boo = models.OneToOneField(Boo)
    foo = models.ManyToManyField(
          Boo, 
          blank=True, 
          null=True, 
          related_name='child_set'
    )
```

Now you can do:

```
Coo.objects.get(pk=1).foo
```

And then you can get by '_set' with:

```
Coo.objects.get(pk=1).boo.child_set
```