# Self Referencing Symmetrical Many to Many Django Model in Admin or View

Tags: django, django-models, many-to-many, django-orm

How do you get the other side of a symmetrical self reference in a M2M django model?

Say we are making a parts catalog, and we have lots of `Part`s and we want to have an `Interchange` to show which parts can be used in place of another:

```
class Part(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    number = models.CharField(max_length=200, default 'because numberphiles like more ids')
    …
    interchanges = models.ManyToManyField("self",
                                          through='Interchange',
                                          symmetrical=False,
                                          # + sign per http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/
                                          # I have tried without the plus t omaintain the references as well, but can't seem to understand the difference(s)
                                          related_name="interchanges_to+",
                                          # through_fields per docs
                                          through_fields=('reference', 'interchange')
                                          )

    # per this http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/
    def add_interchange(self, part, symm=True):
        interchange = models.Interchange.objects.get_or_create(
            reference_part=self,
            interchange_part=part)
        if symm:
            # avoid recursion by passing `symm=False`
            part.add_interchange(self, False)
        return interchange

    def remove_interchange(self, part, symm=True):
        models.Interchange.objects.filter(
            reference_part=self,
            interchange_part=part).delete()
        if symm:
            # avoid recursion by passing `symm=False`
            part.remove_interchange(self, False)

    def get_interchanges(self):
        return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.interchanges.filter(interchange_part__reference=self)])

    def get_references(self):
        return …?
        # This is where I don't know how to get the Parts that are referring to it as being an interchange

class Interchange(models.Model):
    reference = models.ForeignKey(Part, related_name="reference_part")
    interchange = models.ForeignKey(Part, related_name="interchange_part")
    # just to confirm we have a M2M table, we will add a foregin key to a User if this interchange has been personally verified
    confirmed_by = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
    # … others if needed

    class Meta:
        # because self-referencing, in this case, is silly, we make sure each part references another part
        unique_together = ('reference', 'interchange')
```

in the Django admin, I have:

```
@admin.register(app.Part)
class PartAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['name', 
                    'number', 
                     # ▼ I can see the Parts itself Interchanges to
                    'get_interchanges', 
                     # ▼ I can not see the Parts that reference itself as being an Interchange
                    'get_references']
```

Parts Model in admin for reference...

Here is what I have:
[image: Current Models without symmetrical references]

Here is what I am trying to get:
[image: What I am trying to get with symmetrical references]

As a confirmation, the Interchange Model in admin:
[image: Interchange Model]

How do you get the other side of symmetrical self-reference M2M django models?
**How do I return `Part`s that are in the interchange table but in the reference (first) column**

Notes:

- using django 1.11
- I know that the symmetry being `False` is required when using a M2M through Model per the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships)
- [This](http://charlesleifer.com/blog/self-referencing-many-many-through/) nice write-up helped me get quite far, but in the admin, I can't seem to get the `interchange_part` to show its `reference_part`s in the admin page (thusly I haven't even tried to see if it is possible in a view with different/particular function)
- In the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through_fields) it states the second part of the tuple for `through_keys` is called the `target` model, but I cant find out what to refer to the first one
- I am sure that there is a way to go multiple levels deep, ie if part one interchanges to 2, and 2 => 3, then 1 should list 2 and 3 (but that isn't the focus at the moment)
- Please correct my misunderstandings, Thanks :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django: How to follow ManyToMany('self') backwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14228193/django-how-to-follow-manytomanyself-backwards)

Comment: I showed the difference, and was able to make an answer :) ww

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the manytomany has a through table with a `related_name` parameter and does NOT include the `+`, then you can just access the set directly :

```
def get_references(self):
    return ", ".join([str(p) for p in self.interchanges_to.all()])
```

Note, I am unsure about performance/complexity